# How to Declare a 32-bit Integer in C

Tags: c, portability

What's the best way to declare an integer type which is always 4 byte on any platforms? I don't worry about certain device or old machines which has 16-bit `int`.

Comment: In C, a byte does not have to be 8 bits, so 32-bits and 4 bytes could mean different things.

Comment: @KTC: are there any platforms that define byte differently?

Comment: I am also curious to know where char!=8bits and a byte!=8bits. char!=8bits seems ok, as I can have char==4bits in my own undesigned system or some old system, but where does byte!=8bits ??

Comment: Wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) has a nice history of the usage, and examples where byte != 8-bits. They are rarer today than they used to be, but the C standard is careful to avoid the assumption.

Comment: @seg.server.fault, In C (and C++), char === 1 byte. It just doesn't have to have 8 bits. The number of bit is defined as CHAR_BIT in <limits.h>, which has to be at least 8.

Comment: I used to use a machine called Cyber something made by CDC, which has 9-bit byte. But I assume these days are long gone.

Comment: Quite a few DSPs and the like have 16bit chars (and C has no concept of a "byte" other than char - it is in effect the smallest addressable unit of memory).

Comment: As an existence proof, have a table: http://www.insidedsp.com/Articles/tabid/64/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/178/Getting-Better-DSP-Code-Out-of-Your-Compiler.aspx

Comment: One of the Honeyboxen we still have has 6-bit and 9-bit bytes based on the addressing mode you're in.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
#include <stdint.h>

int32_t my_32bit_int;
```

Comment: Just to note intN_t (and uintN_t) is optional in terms of standard. It is required to be defined if and only if the the system has types that meet the requirement.

Comment: That's what you want though. If the code really requires a 32-bit int, and you try to compile it on a platform that doesn't support them, you *want* the compiler to punt back to the developer. Having it pick some other size and go on would be horrible.

Comment: Note that the header '`<inttypes.h>`' is explicitly documented to include the header '`<stdint.h>`' (this is not usual for C headers), but the '`<inttypes.h>`' header may be available where '`<stdint.h>`' is not and may be a better choice for portability.  The '`<stdint.h>`' header is an invention of the standards committee, and was created so that free-standing implementations of C (as opposed to hosted implementations - normal ones) only have to support '`<stdint.h>`' and not necessarily '`<inttypes.h>`' too (it would also mean supporting '`<stdio.h>`', which is otherwise not necessary).

Comment: Is there a way to define the int32_t as unsigned?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst, `uint32_t`.

Comment: I used this in my code for a 32 bit number which broke it, I used `uint32_t` instead which worked.

Answer (score 15):

C doesn't concern itself very much with exact sizes of integer types, C99 introduces the header [stdint.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h) , which is probably your best bet. Include that and you can use e.g. `int32_t`. Of course not all platforms might support that.

Answer (score 12):

Corey's answer is correct for "best", in my opinion, but a simple "int" will also work in practice (given that you're ignoring systems with 16-bit int).  At this point, so much code depends on int being 32-bit that system vendors aren't going to change it.

(See also why long is 32-bit on lots of 64-bit systems and why we have "long long".)

One of the benefits of using int32_t, though, is that you're not perpetuating this problem!

Comment: There's no need to “ignore systems with 16-bit int”, long is guaranteed to be at least 32-bit wide everywhere.

Comment: Right, but using "long" doesn't address the initial request, which is something that's exactly 32 bits.  On (at least some flavors of) 64-bit Linux, for example, a long is 64 bits -- and that's something that's likely to come up in actual practice.

Answer (score 5):

You could hunt down a copy of Brian Gladman's `brg_types.h` if you don't have `stdint.h`.

`brg_types.h` will discover the sizes of the various integers on your platform and will create typedefs for the common sizes:  8, 16, 32 and 64 bits.

Comment: Actually in looking at a few "brg_types.h" I found, this file only defines unsigned integers (eg. "uint_8t", "uint_16t", "uint_32t" and "uint_64t"). The OP needed signed integer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to include `inttypes.h` instead of `stdint.h` because `stdint.h` is not available on some platforms such as Solaris, and `inttypes.h` will include `stdint.h` for you on systems such as Linux. 
If you include `inttypes.h` then your code is more portable between Linux and Solaris.

This link explains what I'm saying:
[HP link about inttypes.h](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801?ciid=a868e67018695110VgnVCM100000275d6e10RCRD)

And this link has a table showing why you don't want to use `long` or `int` if you have an intention of a certain number of bits being present in your data type.
[IBM link about portable data types](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-port64/index.html#N10063)

Answer (score 4):

#### C99 or later

Use `<stdint.h>`.

If your implementation supports 2's complement 32-bit integers then it must define `int32_t`.

If not then the next best thing is `int_least32_t` which is an integer type supported by the implementation that is at least 32 bits, regardless of representation (two's complement, one's complement, etc.).

There is also `int_fast32_t` which is an integer type at least 32-bits wide, chosen with the intention of allowing the fastest operations for that size requirement.

#### ANSI C

You can use `long`, which is guaranteed to be at least 32-bits wide as a result of the minimum range requirements specified by the standard.

If you would rather use the smallest integer type to fit a 32-bit number, then you can use preprocessor statements like the following with the macros defined in `<limits.h>`:

```
#define TARGET_MAX 2147483647L

#if   SCHAR_MAX >= TARGET_MAX
  typedef signed char int32;
#elif SHORT_MAX >= TARGET_MAX
  typedef short int32;
#elif INT_MAX   >= TARGET_MAX
  typedef int int32;
#else
  typedef long int32;
#endif

#undef TARGET_MAX
```

Answer (score 1):

If stdint.h is not available for your system, make your own.  I always have a file called "types.h" that have typedefs for all the signed/unsigned 8, 16, and 32 bit values.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare 32 bits with signed or unsigned long.

```
int32_t variable_name;
uint32_t variable_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

also depending on your target platforms you can use autotools for your build system

it will see if stdint.h/inttypes.h exist and if they don't will create appropriate typedefs in a "config.h"

Answer (score 0):

stdint.h is the obvious choice, but it's not necessarily available.

If you're using a portable library, it's possible that it already provides portable fixed-width integers.
For example, SDL has `Sint32` (S is for “signed”), and GLib has `gint32`.