# `int` type size int C

Tags: c, integer, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is int in C Always 32-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231147/is-int-in-c-always-32-bit)

AFAIK, in Pascal size of Integer depends on the platform (on 32-bit computers it has 32 bits, and on 64-bit computers it has 64 bits).

Is this the same in C (I mean, on 32-bit computers its size is 32 bits, and on 64-bit it is 64)?

Comment: @Mark: thanks, I don't found that question...

Comment: Obviously everyone is correct that it's implementation-dependent, but with specific reference to what you say about Pascal: it is *not* the case in C that `int` is typically 64 bits on a 64 bit system. In practice it tends to be 16 bits on 16-bit systems and 32 bits on everything else, but with some exceptions to that tendency.

Comment: The C standard defines `int˙ as the "natural word size of the computer" - so it definitely can be 64-bit on a 64-bit system.

Comment: @H2CO3: it is true that it can be, it's just that the question suggests to me that the questioner might *expect* it to be. The average reader might think that "the natural word size" of a 64 bit Intel processor is 64 bits, but the average C implementer disagrees. The standard says, "A "plain" `int` object has the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment", implementers read that either as non-normative or as allowing leeway in the meaning of "natural size" -- take your pick what you'd like to accuse them of :-)

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much but compiler has control.  Use the `sizeof` operator if you just want to check what is happening in your environment.  stddef.h will include types like `int64_t` (I think in that file) if you need to make sure # of bytes is fixed and not leave this up to environment/compiler.

Answer (score 2):

It's not only dependent on the processor architecture, but the operating system as well.  The C Language Specifications do not mention the size of the integer types, so that task is the job of the implementor of the language.  Look at the top voted answer here for more background:

[What is the bit size of long on 64-bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows)

In summary, on both Linux and Windows, 'int' will be 32-bit.  For other platforms, you'll have to check their specifications in their C compiler documention.  The best practice, however, is to use the types found in `<inttypes.h>` -- `uint32_t`, `int32_t`, `uint64_t`, `int64_t`.

On Windows, it's a bit tougher; `inttypes.h` is part of C99, for which Visual C++ doesn't claim compliance.  You can get `inttypes.h` from projects like http://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/, or use `<windows.h>` -- `INT32`, `INT64`, `UINT32`, `UINT64`.  There's also the Microsoft extensions `__int32`, `__int64`, `__uint32`, `__uint64`, which you don't need any additional header file for.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the use of exact-width integers. Note: `stdint.h` is also usable from Windows, apparantly!?

Answer (score 1):

C does not define the size of its integer types. YOu have to read the compiler manual

Only rule is sizeof char <= sizeof short <= sizeof int <= sizeof long

Comment: IIRC, long is required to be at least 32 bits, long long at least 64, int at least 16, and char at least 8. I can't recall what that might be for short though.

Comment: @KendallFrey I'm pretty certain those sizes are given in *bytes* AKA `char` sizes. There are platforms where a `char` is not 8 bit.

Comment: @delnan, it's good that you aren't too sure. No actual sizes are given, but certain minimum bit-widths are implied by the required minimum range.

Comment: @eq- That's entirely possible, thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: Also note that the restrictions on *sizes* don't imply corresponding restrictions on *range*, since `short` could have padding bits that make it bigger in `sizeof` than `char` but with the same range of values. This would be perverse, but not actually forbidden by the `sizeof` ordering. I think the integer promotion rules imply though that `int` has at least as many value bits as `char` or `short`, so there are some restrictions on the relative ranges.

Answer (score 1):

That decision is made by the compiler, you can see what the size of an integer is in your specific case in bytes by typing this: `printf("%d", (int)sizeof(int));`.

I highly suggest however that you do not write code that is dependent on the size of `int` being a specific amount.

Answer (score 0):

That's right.  It depends on the platform.

However, the usual practice these days is to make an `int` 32 bits on either a 32-bit or a 64-bit computer.  The `long int` type is 64 bits on a 64-bit computer, and the `long long int` type is 64 bits even on a 32-bit computer.

As @E_Net4 correctly observes, the C++ standard permits considerable variation from the above answer, which speaks only to today's usual practice.  (The C++ standard permits such variation because it wishes to leave a compiler free to define `int` and `long int`, not to mention `short int`, in ways that maximize a particular processor's performance.)

Comment: `long long int` actually means it will be *at least* 64 bits. Same thing for `long int`, which is at least 32-bits big.

Comment: @E_net4:  You are right, of course.