# Writing 32 bit Numbers to SQLITE3 Database (C)

Tags: c, tcp, sqlite, network-programming

I've got a program that reads 32-bit unsigned int values off the wire when stores them in an SQLITE3 database then retrieves them but somewhere along the line the data is being lost.

```
// The data is captured off the wire

//Stored and printed as a 32-bit number 
int32_t seq_num = ntohl(tcp->th_seq); // tcp->th_seq is the number
printf("Seq Num: %" PRIu32 "\n", seq_num);

// Function delcaration (variable as 32bit int)
void addPacket(int table, char *srcIP, char *dstIP, int port, int32_t seq_num);

// Function called with 32bit sequence number
addPacket(0, result1, result2, ntohs(tcp->th_dport), seq_num);
```

This is the SQLITE create database statement:

```
sql1 = "CREATE TABLE synpackets ("  \
       "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," \
       "srcIP VARCHAR(64)," \
       "dstIP VARCHAR(64)," \
       "dstPort int(4)," \
       "seq int(64)," \ // Could this be the problem?
       "timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
```

And this is how I bind the parameter during the INSERT statement:

```
sqlite3_bind_int64(stmt, 4, seq_num);
```

When I read the numbers back out doing `SELECT * ...` I'm getting some negative numbers instead of the values that I intended to go in:

This is the original capture as it's happening **before** it goes into the database:

```
Packet number 38:
Seq Num: 1118349056

Packet number 39:
Seq Num: 768809646
```

And this is the same packet but **after** it's been retrieved from the database:

```
id = 1
seq = 1118349056

id = 2
seq = -1752457962
```

I've looked at the database file at the negative number is being written to the table so it's not just a printing error. Something seems to be going wrong when I try to insert the 32-bit numbers to the database, but I'm unsure what.

Comment: let's begin by realizing that `int32_t` is not an unsigned type.

Comment: Oh, I copied the idea from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229131/how-to-declare-a-32-bit-integer-in-c
Is that whats causing the problem?

Comment: that'd be `uint32_t`.

Comment: ha, wow, that seems to have fixed it, im not getting any negative numbers, thanks

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, you should write that up as an answer so it can be accepted.